# OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter not working with shiro

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data, shiro

I have a Spring MVC app, Using Shiro for authentication. I have configured

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
```

But it's giving error

```
Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:510)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.coupon.domain.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:348)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:224)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:155)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:256)
    at org.apache.jsp.cpanel.user.user_002ddetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(user_002ddetails_jsp.java:1139)
    at org.apache.jsp.cpanel.user.user_002ddetails_jsp._jspService(user_002ddetails_jsp.java:331)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    ... 36 more
2015-12-23 20:30:52 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:989 - Could not complete request
```

In log it shows that filter is configured properly.
**web.xml**

```
 <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>coupon</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- The filter-name matches name of a 'shiroFilter' bean inside applicationContext.xml -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <!-- spring open in view filter -->
    <filter>
         <filter-name>openEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
          <filter-class>
              org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter
          </filter-class>
          <init-param>
              <param-name>entityManagerFactoryBeanName</param-name>
              <param-value>entityManagerFactory</param-value>
          </init-param>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
          <filter-name>openEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
          <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring config file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <context:component-scan annotation-config="true"
        base-package="com.coupon.*" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:db.properties" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <!-- <mvc:default-servlet-handler /> -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Datasource with a c3p0 poolable connection pool -->
    <bean name="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />

        <!-- these are C3P0 properties -->
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${c3p0.acquireIncrement}" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.coupon" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <!-- http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/springsecurity.html -->
    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
        <property name="loginUrl" value="/cpanel/login" />
        <property name="successUrl" value="/cpanel/home" />
        <property name="filterChainDefinitions">
            <value>
                /cpanel/** = authc, anAlias
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="openEntityManagerFilter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter">
        <property name="entityManagerFactoryBeanName" value="entityManagerFactory"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="realm" ref="myRealm" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="myRealm" class="com.coupon.shiro.PortalHibernateRealm"></bean>
    Enable Shiro Annotations for Spring-configured beans. Only run after 
        the lifecycleBeanProcessor has run:
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"
        depends-on="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />
    <bean
        class="org.apache.shiro.spring.security.interceptor.AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace shows the shiro filters isnt even called. If your intention is to first have a shiro login action and then loading the hibernate objects, you should put the shiro filter first, so change the ordering like so:

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openEntityManagerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: My problem is with lazy load org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of